# Activeadmin: destroy / add has_many relations content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, activeadmin

I have this 2 models (echanges and echange_answers) in a relation:

> has_many 
>   / 
>   belongs_to

```
#Model Echange
class Echange < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title
  validates_presence_of :title, :content, :section_id
  validates :section_id, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validates :title, length: { :minimum => 3 }
  validates :content, length: { :minimum => 3 }

  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :echange_answers
end
```

and

```
#Model EchangeAnswer
class EchangeAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  validates_presence_of :content
  validates :content, length: { :minimum => 3 }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :echange
end
```

And here is what i got in active admin :
A list of all the "echanges" made

[image: List of echanges]

And here is the show of one of the echange. I print on the page all the echange_answer that are in a belongs_to relation with this echange.
[image: Show page of a echange]

I would like to set a delete / edit action on each echange_answer in that table and the possibility for the admin to add a new echange_answer.
I am wondering if the best way is not to create a new active_admin:resource and remove the "index" page or to custom the echange page in activeadmin.
If the custom is the best way, how could i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have ActiveAdmin I would use it by making a resource for echange_answer and letting ActiveAdmin handle all the views and actions for you. In your ActiveAdmin echange_answers controller just make sure you have the line below and then you don't have to worry about having any unnecessary controller actions.

```
  actions :only => [:create, :edit, :destroy]
```